# How to configure JNDI connection pooling for more than one database?

Tags: java, jdbc, jndi, connection-pooling, deployment-descriptor

I have one database JNDI connection pooling setup *context.xml* JNDI resources and web.xml env-ref and initial context. It is working good. But I need to build two more database for my application.

So do I have to configure two more JNDI resources and env-ref and initial context separately? Or same env-ref for three databases?

What is the efficient way to build connection pooling for more than one database? Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty much right about having to configure JNDI resources separately. The only thing that in *web.xml* there is NO `<env-ref>` element, but `<resource-env-ref>` and `<resource-ref>` elements.

In order to use more databases, you have to make the following additional configurations **for each resource**:

1. add a new `<Resource>` in *context.xml* file
2. add a new `<resource-ref>` or `<resource-env-ref>` in *web.xml* file

NOTE:
If you use [`@Resource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html) annotation, the new resource no longer needs to be defined in the deployment descriptor (*web.xml*). This annotation is equivalent to declaring a *resource-ref*, *message-destination-ref* or *env-ref*, or *resource-env-ref* element in the deployment descriptor.

And accordingly you have to **separately lookup each** [*DataSource*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) from the [*InitialContext*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html) (you can look up the required DataSource once and then just use the same instance).

---

## Example

The below is an example of configuring two MySQL databases from one of my projects. One database is configured utilizing [The Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html), another without connection pooling (you can do it however you like/need).

*context.xml* (located in /META-INF directory):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <!-- Configuration for primary DB -->
    <Resource   name="jdbc/TestShopDB"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                auth="Container"
                factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
                driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_shop"
                username="root"
                password="mysql"
                maxActive="100"
                minIdle="10"
                initialSize="10"
                validatonQuery="SELECT 1"
                validationInterval="30000"
                removeAbandoned="true"
                removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
                abandonWhenPercentageFull="50"
                closeMethod="close"/>

    <!-- Configuration for administration DB -->            
    <Resource   name="jdbc/TestShopAdminDB"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                auth="Container"
                driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_shop_admin"
                username="root"
                password="mysql"/>      
</Context>
```

*web.xml* (located in /WEB-INF directory; unrelated parts are omitted for the sake of brevity):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        version="3.0">

    ...

    <!-- Configuration for primary DB -->
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestShopDB</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

    <!-- Configuration for administration DB -->
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestShopAdminDB</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

    ...

</web-app>
```

---

### Additional reading

- [Apache Tomcat 7: JNDI Resources
  HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html)
- [Apache Tomcat 7: JNDI Datasource
  HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)
- [Apache Tomcat 7: The Context
  Container](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html)
- [Tomcat Expert: Configuring JDBC Pool for High
  Concurency](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/04/01/configuring-jdbc-pool-high-concurrency)
- [JavaRanch Journal: JDBC Connection Pooling Best
  Practices](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200601/JDBCConnectionPooling.html)